# How to open developer tools in your browser for a tab that closes quickly and automatically

Tags: web, firefox-developer-tools

I want to see what HTTP request was made (through the network tab in dev tools) in a specific tab. The problem is the tab is automatically opened on a click of a button to provide you a download form and is immediately closed.